# MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-firewall

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:832:32)
        at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10
        at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
        at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)
        at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Working\SB\app.js:305:10)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)       
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map {
          'smile-shard-00-00.xeyqd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],  
          'smile-shard-00-01.xeyqd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],  
          'smile-shard-00-02.xeyqd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]   
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

I have already update IP address to mongodb network access => IP Access list to 0.0.0.0/0
But the error has still occurred. I think this error is occurring due to the window firewall. But I have not any idea to resolve this.

Comment: Sometimes Mongo Atlas settings don't apply instantly.
Or the port on your machine via which you are trying to connected can be blocked (it's easy to check if you can connect on your PC, but couldn't via GCP machine) so watch for firewall egress rules. So this error has to do nothing with Mongoose or Mongo itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : “Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859081/error-could-not-connect-to-any-servers-in-your-mongodb-atlas-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday, I solved it by creating a user with the atlasAdmin Role.

Note: Make sure you have your IP in Network Access.